# Angular Creating Dynamic Component Inside Desired Component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am trying to create a component inside `html table`'s each td child dynamicly.
I created a `table` component like following code (inside `app.component.html`)

```
<div class="container">
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col" *ngFor="let column of columns">{{column}}</th>
         </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody #preGrid id="focusItem">

    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

`app.component.ts` file seems as follow.

```
ngOnInit() {
    let tableItem = document.getElementById("focusItem");
    let lastTR;
    for (let i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
      if (i % this.columns.length == 0) {
        let tr = document.createElement("tr");
        tableItem.appendChild(tr);
      }
      lastTR = this.getLastNode(tableItem);
      let td = document.createElement("td");
      lastTR.appendChild(td);

      const factory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(
        CustomInputComponent
      );
      this.container.createComponent(factory);
    }
  }
```

I am trying to create angular components by dynamicly using `ComponentFactoryResolver`.To draw this component, I used `ViewContainerRef`.But seems, it is not true way to do this.Coz I cannot create my `CustomInputComponent` inside td component via this way.
What I am trying to do is, embeding CustomInputComponent inside each td elements.You can see what I wrote till now [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-b4hlza).

Comment: What result are you getting? That would help us better understand your issue.

Comment: I would also recommend using `@ViewChild('preGrid', { read: ViewContainerRef }) entry: ViewContainerRef;` instead of `document.getElementById`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create an array of object which will have the props as well as the type of component you want to render, then in the html portion you can have an `ngFor` loop to iterate over that array of object. Inside the `ngFor` loop have multiple `ngSwitchCase` to render the correct control for the current iteration.

Please see this link : https://codeburst.io/angular-dynamic-forms-ng-switch-approach-4f267c01d2c6

Comment: thank you, I probably tried to fix the problem by hard way.it's easier acording to my solution...